# Populating the values from mysql in a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

the code works but the values are not populated from my database table. it shows an empty dropdown. Please give me some suggesstions friends.

Thanks in Advance...

`enter code here`

```
<?php 
$mysql_hostname = "host";
  $mysql_user = "uname";
 $mysql_password = "pass";
 $mysql_database = "dbname";
  $prefix = "";
 $db = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) 
    or die("Could not connect database");
 //echo "hurray!!!connection successful";
//$query = ("SELECT teacherid,fname from tablename") ;
?>
<table>
<tr>  
<td>teacher name</td>  
 <td><select name="teacherr_name">  
  <?php  
   $query = 'SELECT teacherid,fname FROM teacher_master';  

    $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));  

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {  

    echo '<option value="' . $row['teacherid'] . '"> ' . $row['fname'] .     '</option>';  

  }  
 ?>  
 </select></td>  
  </tr>  
  </table> 

   </html>
```

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated now try with `msqli`. Also are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to select the database, after you've connected to the database server:

```
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db);
```

needless to say that this is the old way of doing it and it will be depricated...

Answer (score 2):

Have you selected the database to work with??? You can do this by

```
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to select your database

```
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($mysql_database, $db);
```

Add this line after you made the connection. Also convert all your mysql statements to `mysqli`. For more details see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

Answer (score 0):

maybe...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  

 echo '<option value="' . $row['teacherid'] . '"> ' . $row['fname'] .     '</option>';  

}
```

Even if mysql command are deprecated you can try using the mysql_fetch_array to obtain a "row" and access it array style. You need first to check what you have at db, that's for sure.

Comment: in $db you need to put the dbname =) you haven't. there are 2 constructor of mysql_connect, one have the dbname, one not. If you don't specify the db you need to use mysql_select_db, you haven't from your code shown.

Answer (score 0):

> select database from where you want to fetch data

```
mysql_select_db('database name','connection variable');
```